# Resize Control with Java JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, resize, jsplitpane

Please see my image below at the link and then read below it for more details on my problem.

[image: Sample image]

Imagine that is a Basic frame splited into two with a JSplitPane, by default when you resize your frame the gray part changes it's size, but I would like the white part to resize accordingly to the frame resizing.

Any help into the right direction would be appreciated as I am working on a project now and I am trying out all kind of weird stuff to be prepared for my biggest project set in the new year. :)

Regards
Theron

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `setResizeWeight` to get the left and right take the extra space or reduce in size on JFrame resize, sample code below:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

    public class TestJSplitPane {
    private void init(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(new JButton("Here I Am"));
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(new JButton("Me Too"));
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        frame.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJSplitPane().init();
    }
}
```

Java Doc for [setResizeWeight](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight%28double%29).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but as in you example now, I would like the right component's size to stay static on resize and add the extra size to the left one.

Comment: instead of splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5) in the above example make it splitPane.setResizeWeight(1.0), that will ensure that right component doesnt take extra space on resize.

Comment: mprabhat, Thanks very much, got it right, it works now. Do any of you maybew have a link to a tutorial on how to work with JMenuBar's and Synth LAF?

Comment: From Oracle docs: Synth LAF - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html , JMenu - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html